# IBM Mobile First 6.3 - getting new persistent cookie instead of expected cookie

Tags: cookies, windows-phone, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to get the persistent Cookie of an IBM mobile First application on windows phone 8.1 with `WL.Server.getActiveUser('wl_anonymousUserRealm').userId`.
But on each instance (each application startup), I'm getting a **new** persistent Cookie.

I'm not facing this issue with the other environments like IOS or Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens due to the following logged APAR: *PI43710 WL.Client.getUserPref/SetUserPref is not working in Windows Phone 8*.

A fix for this issue can be found in the latest iFix for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3, which you can download from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=6.3.0.0&platform=Mac%20OSX&function=fixId&fixids=6.3.0.0-MFPF-IF201509071448&includeRequisites=0&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http).

Make sure to login with your customer credentials.

Comment: The issue is fixed with the latest MobileFirst 6.3 iFix. Thank you.